# Mamba stalls on creating environment from yaml on Ubuntu 22 EC2 instance that works perfectly on local machine

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, conda, mamba

I am trying to spin up a Python web application on an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 22. I am using `mamba` as a package manager and have the packages written into an `environment.yml` file. Running `mamba env create --file=environment.yml` works perfectly for creating a virtual environment (and running the app) on my local machine. However, on my new EC2 instance, the process stops after printing `Looking for: ['python=3.11', 'langchain', 'openai', 'tiktoken', 'pandas', 'streamlit', 'pip']` and then waiting about 5 seconds. I don't know if the issue is coming from something related to Ubuntu, EC2, or mamba and I am unsure how to troubleshoot this.

The entirety of commands run on this instance so far:

```
# download and install mamba 
curl -L -O "https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Mambaforge-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh"
bash Mambaforge-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh
git clone https://github.com/username/repo
mamba env create --file=environment.yml
```

The contents of `environment.yml`

```
name: environment-name
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.11
  - langchain
  - openai
  - tiktoken
  - pandas
  - streamlit
  - pip

  - pip:
    - streamlit-authenticator
```